# How to encode compound predicate into PMML?

Tags: pmml

I am very new to pmml and looking for an example on how to create a a derived field for the following logic?

```
if var1 < 100 and var2 <= -1 then binvalue '--'
else if var1 >= 100 and var2 <= -1 then bin value = '+-'
else if var1 >= 100 and var2 > -1 then binvalue = '++'
else if var1 < 100 and var2 var2 >-1 then binvalue = '-+'
```

I have the outline I think but could be wrong there too.  Any help would be great even if just the first bin maybe.  Amy I going the right direction? Sorry for such a noob question.

```
<DerivedField>
    <Discretize field="myvar"  optype="categorical" datatype="string"   >
        <DiscretizeBin binValue="--">
        </DiscretizeBin> 
        <DiscretizeBin binValue="+-">
        </DiscretizeBin>  
        <DiscretizeBin binValue="++">
        </DiscretizeBin>  
        <DiscretizeBin binValue="-+">
        </DiscretizeBin>   
    </Discretize>
</DerivedField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Discretize` element operates on a single continuous feature. Your requirement is to apply discretization to a pair of continuous features (`var1` and `var2`), which is not supported.

Things you may consider:

- Discretize both features independently, and then map their combinations (two by two matrix of "+" and "-" symbols?) to desired outputs using the `MapValues` element.
- Express the discretization logic using the general-purpose `Apply` element (using `if`, `lessThan` and `greaterThan` built-in functions).